# Tabla en html con información de dos usuarios en una misma tabla

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Tengo una tabla llamada procesos en la cual tengo el id de los 2 usuarios un campo es claimant y el otro es dependant los cuales estan relacionados a la tabla de usuarios por su id

Quiero mostrar los dos usuarios en td diferentes de una tabla html

Migracion de procesos

```
Schema::create('processes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('process_type');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id'); //Id del servicio
            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('claimant')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('claimant')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->string('defendant');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('dependant_id')->nullable(); //Id de encargado del proceso
            $table->foreign('dependant_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('office');
            $table->string('filed');
            $table->enum('status', ['pendiente', 'aprovado','rechazado'])->default('pendiente');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Migracion de usuarios

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('identification')->unique()->comment('Número de identificación');
            $table->enum('identification_type',['cc','nit','ps','ce','ti'])->default('cc');
            $table->enum('person_type',['natural','legal'])->default('natural');
            $table->enum('gender_type',['m','f','o']);
            $table->unsignedInteger('department_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('town_id');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('rol');
            $table->foreign('rol')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Controlador

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $services = Service::all();
        $processes = Process::find($id);
        return view('clientes.show_process')->with('processes', $processes)
                                            ->with('services', $services)
                                            ->with('users', $users);
    }
```

Modelo de procesos

```
public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

Modelo de usuario

```
public function process() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Process', 'claimant');
    }
```

Comment: No se entiende tu consulta: ¿qué datos pretender obtener?, tal vez si lo aclaras en función de ello podremos ofrecer una solución

Comment: estoy obteniendo los datos de la tabla procesos pero en el campo de claimant y dependant me aparece es el numero del id en la tabla y lo que quiero es ver en nombre

Comment: Es una relación de 1 a muchos verdad?

Comment: si, de uno a muchos

Comment: un proceso tiene dos usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya pude, tenia que poner el modelo de procesos asi:

```
public function process() 
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Process', 'claimant_id');
}
```

tambien tuve que editar el campo claimant en la base de datos por claimant_id

y en el blade lo llamo por

```
{{ $processes->process->claimant_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes mal creadas las relaciones, ya que si hablamos de **1:N** (ya que la relación 1:2 no existe) entonces los métodos involucrados son:

- `hasMany`
- `belongsTo`

Quedando de esta forma:

En el modelo `Usuario.php` debe ser así:

```
public function process() 
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Process', 'claimant');
}
```

En el modelo `Process` debería ser `users` indicando que un proceso tiene mas de un usuario asignado

```
public function users() 
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Para que ahora si en tu controlador hagas la consulta de esta forma:

```
$procesos = Procesos::with('users')->get();
```

- Finalmente como obtienes una colección, ya lo único que resta es que hagas el recorrido de los valores obtenidos por medio de `foreach`

Dentro de tu vista harías:

```
@foreach($procesos as $proceso)
    {{ $proceso->columna1 }}
    @foreach($proceso->users as $user)
    {{ $user->nombreUno }}
    {{ $user->nombreDos }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

- Requieres 2 foreach, uno para la entidad principal y el segundo para los datos de la entidad secundaria, donde como notas accedo al método `users` que declare en el modelo `Procesos` mas arriba
- Es en el segundo `foreach` donde accedes a los nombres de los 2 usuarios que pertenecen a ese proceso.

Comment: me dice Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\get()

Comment: se me había pasado el símbolo completo @user136950 revisa de nuevo